# How to change name of Cobertura report

Tags: jenkins, cobertura

I am using `Cobertura` plugin for code coverage in `Jenkins` to test multiple python versions in two different docker containers, `rockylinux-8` and `rockylinux-9`. What I am getting after process is finished are two file reports with the same name: `Cobertura Coverage Report`. I would like to be able to change names of these reports to something like `Rocky-8 Coverage Report` and `Rocky-9 Coverage Report`.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555752/how-to-change-value-of-name-column-in-cobertura-report) question but I couldn't find anything newer that works.

Does anybody have any idea how to change names?

[image]

this is part of jenkins pipeline:

```
stages {
        stage ('Execute tests for RockyLinux'){
            parallel {
                stage ('Test Rocky 8') {
                    agent {
                        docker {
                            image 'localhost:5000/rocky-8:latest'
                            args '-u jenkins:jenkins'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo 'Building Rpm...'
                        sh '''
                            pyenv local 3.7.15 3.8.15 3.9.15 3.10.13 3.11.6
                            tox
                            coverage xml --omit=*usr* --omit=*.tox*
                        '''
                        cobertura coberturaReportFile: '**/coverage.xml'
                    }
                }
                stage ('Test Rocky 9') {
                    agent {
                        docker {
                            image 'localhost:5000/rocky-9:latest'
                            args '-u jenkins:jenkins'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo 'Building Rpm...'
                        sh '''
                            pyenv local 3.7.15 3.8.15 3.9.15 3.10.13 3.11.6
                            for version in 37 38 39 310 311; do tox -e py${version}-requests0; done
                            coverage xml --omit=*usr* --omit=*.tox*
                        '''
                        cobertura coberturaReportFile: '**/coverage.xml'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```